# Concept of static and dynamic binding

Tags: java, dynamic, binding

I´m having little diffculties understanding dynamic binding and inheritance in java.
Heres a liitle bit of code:

```
 printer.print(person);                                  // Printer is printing a person, which says: I am a Person
    printer.print(specialPerson);                           // Printer is printing a special person, which says: I am a SpecialPerson
    printer.print((Person)specialPerson);                   // Printer is printing a person, which says: I am a SpecialPerson

    System.out.println(person);                             // I am a Person
    System.out.println(specialPerson);                      // I am a SpecialPerson
    System.out.println((Person)specialPerson);              // I am a SpecialPerson
    System.out.println(((Object)specialPerson).toString()); // I am a SpecialPerson
```

SpecialPerson is a child class of Person here. Both classes override the toString method. Also there is a class Printer which has 2 methods for person and specialperson objects. I understand the first 3 lines: it calls the printer class and executes the method with the matching type. The 3rd line the object is dynamically casted to a person object. But I don´t understand line 6: Why doesnt´t the casting of the object change the method which is called. Isn´t it called by the dynamic type but the static type?

Comment: Because specialperson is still a SpecialPerson, the methods stay the same

Comment: Am I right when I say: the cast operator in line 6 only "changes" the static(type) but because overriding uses dynamic binding the called method stays the same?

Answer (score 0):

If method is declared on the super object you can call it without compilation error and this is early-binding/static polymorphism. Which method will be executed depends on what the dynamic type of the object is and this is late-binding/dynamic polymorphism.

So for example:

```
public class Super {
   public void foo(){};
}

public class Sub extends Super {
   @Override 
   public void foo(){
      System.out.println("sub");
   }

  public void bar(){};
}


Super s1 = new Super();
Super s2 = new Sub();
Sub s3 = new Sub();


s1.foo(); //prints nothing
s2.foo(); // prints "sub"
s3.foo(); // prinss "sub"
s2.bar(); // won't compile even though s2 is really a Sub object
```

Answer (score 0):

In java all overridden methods are *virtual methods* as described [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_function). This differs from other languages such as C++ where you need to use the *virtual* keyword to get this behaviour.

From Wikipedia:

> Virtual functions are resolved 'late'. If the function in question is 'virtual' in the base class, the most-derived class's implementation of the function is called according to the actual type of the object referred to, regardless of the declared type of the pointer or reference. If it is not 'virtual', the method is resolved 'early' and the function called is selected according to the declared type of the pointer or reference.

Since there are only virtual methods in this case the function is called according to the actual type of the object referred to - it doesn't matter if you cast it to some base class object.